# How does cmake the package I type in find_package()

Tags: cmake

It's really common to see people writing `CMakeLists.txt` typing smoething like :

```
find_package(OpenCV)
```

I would like to know how does cmake know what OpenCV is?

When I check `<path_to_your_cmake>/Modules` ,there are lots of `Find***.cmake` ,but I do not see

something like FindOpenCV.cmake ,So I wonder how and where `OpenCV` is defined?

Thanks

Comment: `When I check <path_to_your_cmake>/Modules` It's not that directory, see [`find package` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure). On my system it seems to be in `usr/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake` from `openvc` package

Comment: @KamilCuk I do see the file you said ,it actually defines something  OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS,I just wonder where this name come from or be defined , or it just take the prefix of OpenCVConfig.cmake, and then OpenCV just comes out?

Comment: From the documentation I linked `The command searches for a file called <PackageName>Config.cmake or ....`. It's super long, but it's worth reading anyway. `I just wonder where this name` which name?

Comment: @KamilCuk I read doc you post and see   :  """The command searches for a file called <PackageName>Config.cmake or <lower-case-package-name>-config.cmake""" and """cache entry called <PackageName>_DIR is created to hold the directory containing the file""" .I think these two sentence are what I need to know. THANKS!!

Comment: @KamilCuk Would like to post answer by maybe putting what you've typed together?

Comment: @KamilCuk,May I ask you that why my ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} is empty if not it's not specified , how is it possible to ""find_package"""? Thanks